# Change name of root element when serializing with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I try to change the root name when serializing to XDocument.

I try to serialize a(n inner) class and get the root name `Test.MyClass`.
I try to change it with `XmlRoot` attribute but nothing happens. What is the trick to change the root name? or am I using XDocument for something it cannot do?

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var res = Serialise(new MyClass());
    }

    private static XDocument Serialise(object objectToSerialize)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, objectToSerialize);
        }
        return doc;
    }

    [XmlRoot("NewName")]
    public class MyClass { }
}
```

I get

```
<MyTestClass.MyClass/>
```

but I want

```
<NewName/>
```

Comment: The DataContractSerializer serializer is not recognizing the XmlRoot attribute.  Use XmlSerializer instead.

Comment: As noted [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) you need to use the `DataContract` or `Serializable` attribute on the class you're going to use `DataContractSerializer` on.

Comment: @jdweng Your comment was probably as good as Heritic Monkey's but I chose the latter as Answer. To be honest: I am not that fond of my question to start with - it rakes of lack of research. To the question's defense: Functionality for handling Xml is convoluted and it is hard to figure out the "right way" to do stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) you need to use the `DataContract` or `Serializable` attribute on the class you're going to use `DataContractSerializer` on. The `XmlRoot` attribute is for use with the `XmlSerializer`, as noted by @[jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673193/change-name-of-root-element-when-serializing-with-xdocument/55677121#comment98033841_55673193).